# After successfully downloading Mactex on OS 10.13.1 machine and successfully installing, cannot run TeXShop

Tags: texshop, incompatibility, macos

I am new to LaTeX. After successfully downloading Mactex on new OS 10.13.1 (=High Sierra) machine (md5 were identical) and successfully installing, I cannot run TeXShop. I get this error message:

TeXShop cannot open due to a problem. Check with developer that TeXShop works with this version of MacOS. You may have to reinstall the application. Make sure you install all available updates for the application and for MacOS.(my English translation of French original, below)

(original: "TeXShop ne peut pas s'ouvrir en raison d'un problème. Vérifiez auprès du développeur que TeXShop fonctionne avec cette version de MacOS. Il se peut que vous soyez amené à réinstaller l'application. Assurez-vous de bien installer toutes les mises à jour disponibles pour l'application et pour MacOS.)

Comments:

```
Process:               TeXShop [1288]
Path:                  /Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/Contents/MacOS/TeXShop
Identifier:            TeXShop
Version:               3.77 (3.77)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           TeXShop [1288]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-02-10 09:02:00.620 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.1 (17B1003)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        D74E5C05-84B9-A330-F5E8-39A01EB62AD0


Time Awake Since Boot: 3900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x3] Wrong version

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
  Referenced from: /Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/Contents/MacOS/TeXShop
  Reason: Incompatible library version: TeXShop requires version 1.6.0 or later, but Sparkle provides version 1.5.0

Binary Images:
       0x10cc4f000 -        0x10cd4aff7 +TeXShop (3.77 - 3.77) <A1857A2E-E427-3BF1-9B63-417BB1918DC1> /Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/
```

Comment: You should consider updating your MacOS from 13.3.1 to 13.3.3. The latest version of TeXshop is 3.97, dated 2018-01-10; see http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/ for more information. For what it's worth, I run MacOS 10.13.3 on my Macbook Pro, and I experience no problems with  either MacTeX2017 or TeXshop 3.97.

Comment: Thank you, Mico. I have udated to 13.3.3. That didn't solve the problem; I then dumped the previous TeX install, and redownloaded. Now it works.

Comment: Glad you're up and running!